# how to resolve Unknown column in 'where clause'many clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with SQL to select same information when I hve lot of clause
the first column is unknow in other clause.

This is my sql expression:

```
SELECT * ,
(select sum(sell) from product_details where product_details.product_id = products.id) as total ,
(select sell from product_details where product_details.product_id = products.id order by product_details.id desc limit 1) as ysell ,
(select sum(sell) as wsell FROM (select sell from product_details where product_details.product_id = products.id order by product_details.id desc limit 2 ) as weeksell) as wsell
FROM `products`
```

I try to get information from product and second table is product_details
based on product ID;

ysell = last sell

total = total sell

wsell = limit 7 sell by using sum() and select from the last 7

but whene i run my expression i get error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause'
```

isn't knowing in this line

```
(select sum(sell) as wsell FROM (select sell from product_details where product_details.product_id = products.id order by product_details.id desc limit 2 ) as weeksell) as wsell
```

can you suggest any ideas.

Comment: You can not access an outer table in a subselect. You should learn baout joins

Comment: i want to use one column from the first select table :products

Comment: This is the most unholy SQL query I've ever seen.

Comment: @Havenard that what i can do to resolve my problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that correlation clauses cannot be nested more than one level deep -- hence the reason by `products` is not seen.  One solution is to transform this to conditional aggregation.  That is a bit tricky, but here is one method:

```
SELECT p.* ,
       sum(pd.sell) as total,
       max(case when pd.id = pdd.max_id then pd.sell end) as ysell,
       sum(case when pd.id >= pdd.id7 then pd.sell end) as wsell
FROM products p JOIN
     product_details pd
     ON pd.product_id = p.id JOIN
     (SELECT pd.product_id, MAX(pd.id) as max_id,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pd.id ORDER BY pd.id DESC), ',', 7), ',', -1) as id7
      FROM product_details pd
      GROUP BY pd.product_id
     ) pdd
     ON pdd.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;  -- reasonable assuming `id` is unique/primary key
```

Comment: thanks for help i will use the code to see it and what i can get